# Exclude item from CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to write a CSS selector for this snippet, but without it applying to the `<label>` compoenent? So that I can alter the text in the div, but the label is good where it is.

```
<div id="edit-cc" class="form-item form-type-item">
      <label class="field" for="edit-cc">cc </label>
      guy@example.com, frank@example.com, inne@example.com, jan@example.com, karel@example.com
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way is to enclose all email address in one element (probably an unordered list is the most suitable tag for this purpose) but if you cannot modify the code just apply your rules to the `div {}` and then revert them on `div label {}`

Comment: No, I cannot modify the code... Reverting is a good hint! Thanks

Comment: Reverting seems to me the only suitable solution, without using javascript. Next time, if you have the possibility to effect the code, don't let anything unwrapped. A simple <span> around the addresses would save much time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can `override` those properties which is inside your `div` like this:

```
div{
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}
div label{
    color:red;
    font-weight:normal;   
    font-size:18px;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/3Kkvg/